# What does it mean to express a real number in $n$-base.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, decimal-expansion, number-systems

We usually express real numbers in decimal form. What does it actually mean?

More generally, my question is:

> what is the actual meaning of expressing a real number say between $0$ and $1$ in base-$n$ representation. How to visualize this thing?

Comment: [Positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I know that but I want a visual understanding.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I am especially talking about fractionals.

Comment: You take the interval divide it in $n$ equal parts and write down the interval in which the point is located. Divide that subinterval in $n$ equal parts and write down the subinterval in which it is located. Repeat.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy A diagram would complete my query.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thanks.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Can you help me to answerhttps://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7172290?noredirect=1

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487829/are-there-books-similar-to-hsiung-lins-geometric-linear-algebra-for-abstract?noredirect=1#comment7172290_3487829 this one.